# Exclude mounted folders from tar archive

Tags: linux, backup, mount, tar

we want to backup our server and this seems to be pretty simple thing to do except one. Currently we use something like this:

tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /

Everything is fine, but we do not want to include mount points, as several ftp users has chrooted access to their homes with mounts like:

mount --bind /var/www/folder /home/user/html

Is the any way to exclude such folders from being backuped?

Comment: Does `--one-file-system` do what you're looking for?

Comment: @yoonix: My thought exactly. Only issue would be maybe an external device?

Answer (score 8):

Use the appropriate `tar` command line option:

```
       --one-file-system
              stay in local file system when creating archive
```

Comment: But it doesn't work for mount --bind /var/www/folder /home/user/html

Comment: Are you saying that files appearing under /home/user/html still end up in the archive?

Comment: yes it seems like this is the case

Comment: What about this approach?

mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root -o ro
tar -C /mnt/root -c . (...)

It seems this excludes all mounts from the system. I'm not really sure if it is the best solution though.

Answer (score 2):

The option `--one-file-system` does work, it just needs some very specific syntax.

```
tar -cvzf /mnt/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

works, but

```
tar --one-file-system -cvzf /mnt/backup.tar.gz /*
```

does not.  This is probably because shell globbing will result in the option being applied to each and every subdirectory of / individually.  So /proc gets included because everything in /proc is indeed one file system.

Comment: GNU tar doesn't like the first way

Comment: I fell into the `*` glob trap with this initially. `cd /`ing into the root directory first and then passing `.` to `tar` seems to work, and the `--one-file-system` option appears to skip mount points.